# Вылетает ошибка при загрузке картинок

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте, хочу написать генератор спрайтов и нашел код который вроде как это делает (решил себе облегчить жизнь..), короче вылетает при загрузке изображений, может у кого-то будут идеи чего оно  вылетает?
Переменныне

```
Graphics g;
    int bmHeight = 0;
    int bmWidth = 0;
    int maxImageWidth = 0;
    int maxImage = 0;
    List<List<Image>> ImageList = new List<List<Image>>();
```

Место где вылетает:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK && openFileDialog1.FileName != null)
        {
            List<Image> LineList = new List<Image>();
            int imWidth=0;
            if (openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames.Length > maxImage)
                maxImage = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames.Length;
            foreach (string s in openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames)
            {
                Image im = Image.FromFile(s);
                LineList.Add(im);
                imWidth += im.Width;
                if (im.Width>maxImageWidth)
                    maxImageWidth=im.Width;
            }
            if (imWidth > bmWidth)
                bmWidth = imWidth;
            bmHeight += LineList[0].Height;
            ImageList.Add(LineList);
            CreateImage();
        }
    }
```

Создание изображения:

```
void CreateImage()
    {
        int _bmWidth = checkBox1.Checked ? maxImage * maxImageWidth : bmWidth;
        if (_bmWidth > pictureBox1.Width || bmHeight > pictureBox1.Height)
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        else
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;

        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(_bmWidth, bmHeight);
        label1.Text = "X = " + pictureBox1.Image.Width.ToString();
        label2.Text = "Y = " + pictureBox1.Image.Height.ToString(); 
        g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        int sX = 0;
        int sY = 0;
        foreach (List<Image> li in ImageList)
        {
            foreach (Image i in li)
            {
                if(checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(i, new Point(sX+((maxImageWidth-i.Width)/2), sY));
                    sX += maxImageWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawImage(i, new Point(sX, sY));
                    sX += i.Width;
                }
            }
            sY += li[0].Height;
            sX = 0;
        }
        pictureBox1.Refresh();

    }
```

Ругается во так:
[image]

Фул сайз
http://data1.floomby.com/files/share/22_12_2012/pwWjQsXT5UKV9Caf7hSTEQ.jpg

Comment: Как ругается то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю дело в том что

```
...
bmHeight += LineList[0].Height;
...
```

Тут может не быть LineList[0] если SafeFileNames пустой.

Ну а по сообщению об ошибке всё же ясно - файл не найден. Наверное надо на загрузку подавать полный путь с файлом, а не только его имя (SafeFileName)?

Используйте **FileNames** вместо **SafeFileNames**:

```
foreach (string s in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
```

Comment: файл нейм не пустой, у меня проблема когда я токо загружаю картинки, не сохраняю

Comment: Путь к файлу указывайте, а не только его имя без пути.

Comment: Image im = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName + s);

написал, все так же выдает ошибку

Comment: s Тут лишнее. Image im = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
Добавил обновление в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Поучительный ответ: учите английский, или, хотя-бы, переводите в translate.google.com ошибки которые получаете, сразу станет все понятно.

Comment: тут скорей ошибка во не внимательности... но спасибо за совет (: